# Convert text box text into Argb argument

Tags: c#, graphics

I have been looking into coloring objects like ellipses with code such as

```
        SolidBrush trnsRedBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x78FF0000));
```

I'd like to play around further with this by entering FromArgb's argument into a textbox on a form, then using the textbox to set the Brush's color.  How would I convert the textbox's text into an argument usable by FromArgb?

Comment: I don't know if you know it but there's also a built-in ColorDialog widget you can use, too, instead of typing hex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
someTextBox.Text = "AAFFBBDD";
int param = int.Parse(someTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
SolidBrush trnsRedBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(param));
```

You could shorten this of course.

Edit: Keep in mind if you type something bad this could throw an exception.  There are "TryParse" variants to allow you to handle the situation to your liking.  I won't make a specific recommendation because it depends on the context and scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on entering hexadecimal values into the textbox, why not just do:

```
SolidBrush trnsRedBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text), 16));
```

**Edit**: Have to cast the value to an int first. (oops!)

Comment: Where did you find documentation indicating that FromArgb would accept a string as a parameter?

Comment: AaronLS, you're right, it doesn't. It would have to be parsed first as in your answer.